# Custom Environment Variables Documentation

Tags: symfony, documentation, symfony4

Why is this documentation :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html#custom-environment-variable-processors

suggesting to use a tag (container.env_var_processor) that does not exist in :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html

Answer (score 0):

When documenting the env var processors in https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/10553, it was simply forgotten to add the tag to the reference. Would you like to send a pull request to add it there?